# Mongo date aggregate output Date object

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I need to group datetime field by minute. That's rather easy:

```
db.my_collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "year": { "$year": "$meta_data.created_at" },
            "dayOfYear": { "$dayOfYear": "$meta_data.created_at" },
            "hour": { "$hour": "$meta_data.created_at"},
            "minute": { "$minute": "$meta_data.created_at"}
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}])
```

The problem is that the output is:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "year": 2016,
    "dayOfYear": 349,
    "hour": 16,
    "minute": 43
  },
  "count": 4
}
```

Which is not really convenient if I want to query by Date later on.
How can I make the output of the aggregation back in DateTime object?

Comment: I think the best you can do is concat back them to string in project stage and hopefully in your  code parse them back to datetime object

Comment: But I want to query with a $lt and $gt, so a string won't help me...
The current code is in map reduce which is really problematic (global lock etc.)

Comment: later on meaning later in the aggregation pipeline ?you can still keep created_date object in the group stage using $first and use them in the project stage for example

Comment: @SagarReddy - I'm thinking in this direction - I would have like to have a date stripped out of the seconds and milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

OK - so what I meant in the question is doable by doing:

```
db.my_collection.aggregate([
    {"$group": {
        "_id": {
            "date_by_minute": {"$subtract": [{"$subtract": 

["$meta_data.created_at", 
{"$multiply":[{"$second": "$meta_data.created_at"} , 1000]}]},
    {"$millisecond": "$meta_data.created_at"}]}},
                "count": { "$sum": 1 }
            }}
            ])
```